# Wix Error ICE17: Bitmap: ' is launching

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I'm trying to develop a Wix project. I'm using Wix 3.6, and everything goes perfect, except when I try to change the default interface of Wix to the **WiUI_Mondo** one.

I do the following to change the interface:

1. `Add reference to WixUIExtension.dll`
2. Add `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`

With these simple steps, I should be able to change the interface of my Wix installer. Instead, it is launching an error like this:

```
Error: ICE17: Bitmap: '
```

And **no more text** after the simple comma.

Any idea on why is this happening??

**EDIT: This mistake comes from several .wxs files, such as PrepareDlg.wxs, FilesInUse.wxs...**

Comment: It is not a solution, but I ended up for the moment ignoring the mistake.... :_(

Comment: What you can try is: Get Orca and run the ice again. Maybe you get there a complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason, but you can see in msdn what ice17 is testing:
[ice 17 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: But that is for customized messages. In this case I'm using the basic interface, with no modifications... I saw that page, but as I'm not customizing the interface, only changed the main interafce...